# How to resolve impossible ambiguity with commas? The Oxford comma doesn't help

Tags: grammar

Have there been any solutions proposed for the ambiguity in sentences such as the following?

> The highlights of his global tour include encounters with Nelson Mandela, an 800-year-old demigod‹,› and a dildo collector.

The problem is that although the comma which I have identified using ‹brackets› makes it clear that Nelson Mandela is not a dildo collector, it fails to clarify whether or not he is an 800-year-old demigod. Context clues notwithstanding, the sentence is semantically ambiguous.

Is there a way to use punctuation to resolve the ambiguity? Or does the sentence have to be reworded?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ambiguities go away if you replace the commas with semicolons:

> The highlights of his global tour include encounters with Nelson Mandela; an 800-year-old demigod; and a dildo collector.

This is because semicolons do not also have the potential for marking off a parenthetical comment in the same way that commas do.

Comment: Is this semicolon thing grammatically correct? I guess I've just never seen a list with them

Comment: Yes; semicolons are often used to disambiguate lists, especially when some of the list items are phrases that include the word *and* or parenthetical descriptions. A good example of this usage is contained in one of the comments appended to this [Mental Floss article about the Oxford comma:](http://mentalfloss.com/article/33637/best-shots-fired-oxford-comma-wars) "The guests we need to purchase gifts for are: My sister, the maid of honor; Emily, a bridesmaid and my best friend; Lily, another bridesmaid; Timmy, the best man; Eric, the other groomsman; and both our sets of parents."

Answer (score 3):

You can always rephrase, of course: He met Mandela as well as a god and a collector.